# If I have an Subclass of ArrayList, Can I Iterate over its elements Without Calling super.iterator()?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, collections, arraylist

Say, for example, that I have

```
public class Foo<Game> extends ArrayList<Game>{

 }
```

and I want to iterate over its elements. I'm aware that I can use a for loop with an its iterator. But trying something like:

```
for(Game g : super)
```

does not seem to work. This is mysterious(at least to me) because super is a reference to an object of type `ArrayList<Game>` which should be able to be iterated over. Is there some syntax that I'm missing?

EDIT: I added the Foo type to the class declaration.

Comment: Why did you use `super` instead of `this`?

Comment: `for(Game g : this)` works.  General word of advice though - in this class `Game` is a type parameter; but you've made it look like a type.  The normal convention is just to use a single capital letter for a type parameter.  At a pinch, use a letter and a number (`T1, T2`), but not an entire word.  Otherwise, it's very confusing for people looking at your code, and then expecting there to be a class called `Game` - and even more confusing if there really is a class called `Game`.

Comment: `Game` Is a class though. I only want to store `Game` objects in this arraylist, so I set it to Foo<Game>.

Comment: No, the way you've used it, it's a type parameter, and you've made `Foo` a generic.  If you want it to always be `Game` objects that this thing stores, then declare it as `public class Foo extends ArrayList<Game>` - otherwise you're going to get horribly confused down the track.  That way, you'll also be able to use the methods of the `Game` class within `Foo`.

Comment: In fact, I wouldn't inherit from `ArrayList` *at all*. In most cases, I think you'll find it much easier making `Foo` *have a field* of type `ArrayList<Game>` rather than having it *be* an `ArrayList<Game>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> This is mysterious(at least to me) because super is a reference to an object of type `ArrayList<Game>` [...]

`super` is *not* an object. If you instantiate a class that inherits from another class, you don't get two objects (`this` and `super`), there is only the one instance. (Heck, it'd become unwieldy with deep inheritance hierarchies!) `super` allows you to access methods from the super *class* (again, *not* an object) and use them in your method implementations. Those `super` methods still execute in the context of the `this` object, but now that object is of a subclass type. That's perfectly fine though, and it's one of the foundations for polymorphism.

`this` is an object: it's an instance of `Foo` and, because `Foo` inherits from `ArrayList<Game>`, it is also an `ArrayList<Game>` and thus implements `Iterable<Game>`. Therefore, you can just iterate over `this`.

Thus, you're looking for:

```
for (Game g : this) { ... }
```

Comment: Another way to think of it is that `super` helps identify a method, not an object -- despite its appearance.